# Azure API Management REST API always creates unpublished product

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm working with the [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn776326.aspx) for [Azure API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/), trying to [create a new product](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn776336.aspx#CreateProduct). In the image below I've used a REST client called [Insomnia](http://insomnia.rest/) to create my product:

[image]

I noticed that the product is always created with the `state` property as "Not published", regardless of the value sent:

[image]

Why is the `state` property always "Not published", and how can I create a published product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design, according to [the official doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-add-products/#_add-apis), **before publishing your product you need to add one or more APIs**. In portal, if you publish a product without any apis, you'll get the following result.
[image]
[image]

So you need to add one or more APIs to your product before publishing, either through [portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-add-products/#_add-apis) or [rest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn776336.aspx#AddAPI).

Comment: You right @forester123, I tried adding one API to product and then doing a UPDATE and it works, thx by your time !